# Receiving SyntaxError: EOF while parsing line from STDIN?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a loop-and-a-half where when the user presses `Enter` it kicks out of the loop and gives them their totals.  I added a `try-except` error handler that makes it work, but there has to be another way to keep it from hitting `EOF` when the user enter a blank line.

```
def main():
    cooling_deg_days = 0
    heating_deg_days = 0

while True:
    try:
        usr_in = eval(input('Please enter the average daily temperature in'
                            ' degrees Farenheit: '))
        if usr_in == '':
            break

        if usr_in > 80:
            deg_above = usr_in - 80
            cooling_deg_days += deg_above
            print('{} added to the CDD total.'.format(deg_above))
        elif usr_in < 60:
            deg_below = 60 - usr_in
            heating_deg_days += deg_below
            print('{} added to the HDD total.'.format(deg_below))
    except SyntaxError:
        break

print('Cooling Degree-Days total was {}.'.format(cooling_deg_days))
print('Heating Degree-Days total was {}.'.format(heating_deg_days))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're using `eval()` when you should be using `int()`.

Comment: Would you explain why I should be using `int()`?  I get this error when I change it: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: Because the correct way to parse a string into an integer is with `int()`. `eval()` evaluates whatever the user enters, even if it's not a number but rather a command that does something like _delete the contents of the hard drive_. Check that the string can be turned into an integer before calling `int()`, or use a standard `try..except ValueError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the input is a number with `isdigit()`, then use `int()` instead of `eval()`.

```
while True:
    usr_in = input('Please enter the average daily temperature in'
                        ' degrees Farenheit: ')
    if usr_in.isdigit():
        usr_in = int(input)
    else:
        break

    if usr_in > 80:
        deg_above = usr_in - 80
        cooling_deg_days += deg_above
        print('{} added to the CDD total.'.format(deg_above))
    elif usr_in < 60:
        deg_below = 60 - usr_in
        heating_deg_days += deg_below
        print('{} added to the HDD total.'.format(deg_below))
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.  I guess I was used to the way you could handle empty strings, not empty `int` values.

Comment: It _is_ handling an empty string. Only after it determines that the string is not empty, and doesn't contain anything that isn't a digit, does it try to parse the string into an integer.